# Парсинг шаблонов в фреймворке Gin

Tags: golang, golang-gin

Использую веб-фреймворк [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin), возникла необходимость раскидать tmpl файлы по папкам. Появилась проблема: как теперь их распарсить?

Пример:

```
r = gin.Default()
r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/components/Menu/*") // <-- интересно тут
r.Static("/assets", "./assets")
InitializeRoute() // тут get/post запросы
fmt.Println("Запуск интерфейса авторизации")
log.Println("Запуск интерфейса авторизации", time.Now())
r.Run()
```

Вот как изменить строчку `r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/components/Menu/*")`, чтобы он обрабатывал все файлы лежащие в `templates/*` и дальше по вложенности.

Comment: может так `r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/**/**/*")` ?

Comment: В таком виде он не есть файлы которые находятся в папках нижней иерархии, то есть выдает ошибку если файл в templates/index.tmpl

Comment: Актуально, ребят мне очень нужна помощь в данном вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Загружать шаблоны самостоятельно и готовый шаблон передавать `gin`.

Дело в том, что `LoadHTMLGlob` использует `path/filepath.Glob()`, формат маски аргумента которого описан в документации к функции `Match()` того же пакета. Она в свою очередь рассматривает любую последовательность `*`, будь то `**` или `***`, как одну `*`. Иными словами, она работает только на одном уровне вложенности.

Для того что б распарсить дерево папок в один шаблон можно использовать `path/filepath.Walk()`

Пример.

```java
import (
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    // [...]
)

// [...]

const (
    templatesDir = "templates/" // путь к шаблонам
    templatesExt = ".html"      // расширение файлов-шаблонов
)

func main() {
    r = gin.Default()
    r.SetHTMLTemplate(loadTemplates())

    // [...]
}

func loadTemplates() *template.Template {

    // абсолютный путь к папке
    abs, err := filepath.Abs(templatesDir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // корневой шаблон без имени
    templ := template.New("")

    err = filepath.Walk(abs,
        func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) (_ error) {

            // не обрабатывать необычные файлы
            if !info.Mode().IsRegular() {
                return
            }

            // фильтр по расширению
            if filepath.Ext(path) != templatesExt {
                return
            }

            // относительный путь
            name, err := filepath.Rel(abs, path)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            // именем шаблоны будет относительны
            // путь с обрезанным расширением
            name = strings.TrimSuffix(name, templatesExt)

            nt := templ.New(name)
            b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            _, err = nt.Parse(string(b))
            return err

        })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return templ

}
```

Иными словами `templates/components/Menu/main.html` будет иметь имя `components/Menu/main`. Это позволяет избежать коллизий при наличии файла `main.html` в соседних директориях. При этом общее начало `templates/` как и общий конец `.html` отсекаются.

---

- gin: [LoadHTMLGlob](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.LoadHTMLGlob) | [SetHTMLTemplate](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.SetHTMLTemplate)
- path/filepath: [Glob](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Glob) | [Match](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Match) | [Walk](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Walk) | [Abs](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Abs) | [Rel](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Rel) | [Ext](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Ext)
- html/template: [New](https://godoc.org/html/template#New) | [(*Template).Parse()](https://godoc.org/html/template#Template.Parse) | [(*Template).New()](https://godoc.org/html/template#Template.New)
- os: [FileInfo](https://godoc.org/os#FileInfo) | [FileMode.IsRegular](https://godoc.org/os#FileMode.IsRegular)
- io/ioutil: [ReadFile](https://godoc.org/io/ioutil#ReadFile)